# Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

Tags: mysql, localhost, permissions

I know that there are similar questions, but I didn't find exactly what I'm looking for. Here's what happens and it's kinda strange:

```
[root@xxx xxx]# mysql -u profuser -ppwd -h 192.168.1.99
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'profuser'@'192.168.1.99' (using password: YES)
```

And `192.168.1.99` is my own IP. But when I use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, it's OK:

```
[root@xxx xxx]# mysql -u profuser -ppwd -h 127.0.0.1
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 68
Server version: 5.0.45 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> bye
[root@xxx xxx]# mysql -u profuser -ppwd -h localhost
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 69
Server version: 5.0.45 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x) question, but it didn't help:

```
mysql> select host from user where user='profuser';
+--------------+
| host         |
+--------------+
| 127.0.0.1    | 
| 192.168.1.99 | 
| localhost    | 
+--------------+
```

I added my IP, as advised in the other question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql - Access denied for user 'root'@'x.x.x.x'](http://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x)

Comment: @Chris S - no, it's not :) I even used it in my question ( "I  found this question, but it didn't help:" - there's a link on "here")

Comment: the password for the user 'root'@'192.168.1.99' is almost certainly wrong; which Randy's answer covers from that question. But I'm sure you read that already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the password hash match for the new user/host combo?  Tweak your select statement: `select host, password from user where user='profuser';`

Anyway, what're you attempting to achieve?  You're adding the `-h 192.168.1.99` flag; this isn't necessary when connecting locally (as you've discovered).  If you're going to want to connect over the network, then you'll need a user spec like `'root'@'192.168.1.%'` or `'root'@'%'`, something to allow remote hosts; if you're just doing local connections then you don't need the `-h`.

Comment: Ha! I tried this query and it shows, that there's no password for 'profuser'@'192.168.1.99'! LOL! Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Anyway, what're you attempting to achieve?" - I know, that it's not necessary, but this is a configurable option for an application and I don't know if the client, that will use my app, knows that, so I needed to do some tests for such situation. Anyway, thanks again (:

Comment: @Kiril Fair enough!  But yeah, the straight `GRANT` from that other question doesn't set the password by default. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When adding a host manually using a query like `INSERT INTO mysql.user ...`, you must issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command to apply the changes.

Comment: I tried, it's not working