# delete mysql root user

Tags: mysql, centos

I don't know what I have done, really yesterday everything seems to be working as I wanted but it seems that there's something going on, I cannot no longer login to mysql and I haven't not forgot the password, I have created another user yesterday called example1 gave him all the privileges, by mistake I **think** I deleted the root user but everything was working yesterday, I could login with example1

today it's a different story, I deleted a big table this morning and from there everything is going wrong!

I'm not able to login to my mysql using any method, I uninstalled mysql

```
yum remove mysql
yum remove mysql-server
yum remove mysql-libs
```

and reinstalled it

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

the problem is still there, so reinstalling it didn't work I have to fix the problem

**what's the problem?**

I just wanted to tell you guys that i did reinstall it before i ask the question so you don't suggest that i reinstall it lol and I'm not ready to reinstall the OS because there are too many things there

and now the problem, I'm not sure what it is exactly otherwise I'd fix it myself, so I'm having the same problem as [this guy](https://serverfault.com/questions/230012/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootx-x-x-x) but I tried every solution suggested and none works

you know most of the time it says

`Access denied for user 'root'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: NO)` and if i try to connect to the db it says YES, can i reset everything and start over?

If you need further info tell me, I'm using centos 5 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one helped me out:

Recover MySQL root Password: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described in the docs about how to [reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) may be helpful.  Basically you start mysql in a special mode that disables the need for authentication.  Then you can connect and reset the root password, or possibly recreate it, if you need to.

Another thing you might try would be to simply restore your backup of the mysql system database which goes by the name `mysql` from an older backup.